# QML drag one component as if it has the top stacking order (largest z)

Tags: user-interface, drag-and-drop, qml

QT5.5, QML:

I am using the example "[Qt Quick Examples - Drag and Drop](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-draganddrop-example.html)"
In this example, you could see that if we drag the red tile "1", it appears under other tiles when we drag it.

I don't like this effect since when we drag one item, I hope it always appears on the top of whole GUI.

What I tried is:
Once the mouse is pressed, we set the item's z as the largest value. And when the mouse is released, set the z to the small value (or better we could save the original value and reset it back to its original valule)

```
MouseArea {
        id: mouseArea

        width: 64; height: 64
        anchors.centerIn: parent

        drag.target: tile

        onPressed: {
             tile.z = 100;
        }
        onReleased: {
             tile.z = 0;
             parent = tile.Drag.target !== null ? tile.Drag.target : root
        }
}
```

But the code does not work.
Actually by using console.log, I could see the z value changes, but the dragging ghost image still appears at the bottom.
So I guess when onPressed is implemented, the drag mechanism has used its original z value and gets no chance to access the updated z value.

So any idea to have a more decent drag movement?

Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The [`z`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickitem.html#z-prop) value of items only applies to siblings and the *immediate* (direct) parent:

> Items with a higher stacking value are drawn on top of siblings with a lower stacking order. Items with the same stacking value are drawn bottom up in the order they appear. Items with a negative stacking value are drawn under their parent's content.

Let's use a small example to test the parent/child scenario:

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.0

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 200
    height: 200
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    flags: Qt.FramelessWindowHint

    Rectangle {
        color: "salmon"
        width: 64
        height: 64
        anchors.centerIn: parent

        Text {
            text: "1"
        }

        Rectangle {
            color: "steelblue"
            x: 32
            y: 32
            width: 64
            height: 64

            Text {
                text: "2"
            }

            Rectangle {
                color: "orchid"
                x: 16
                y: -16
                width: 64
                height: 64
                z: -2

                Text {
                    text: "3"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: stacking order]

We set the `z` value of the third `Rectangle` to -2, hoping that it would go behind the first one, but since it's a child of the second and not the first, it's out of reach. This is what's happening in the drag and drop example: the items are too far apart in terms of ancestory.

To elaborate further on this, let's take `DragTile.qml` from the `Drag and Drop` example and modify it in a similar way to yours (this is a nicer way of achieving the same thing, by the way):

```
states: State {
    when: mouseArea.drag.active
    ParentChange { target: tile; parent: root }
    AnchorChanges { target: tile; anchors.verticalCenter: undefined; anchors.horizontalCenter: undefined }
    PropertyChanges {
        target: tile
        z: 100
    }
}
```

This also won't work. To see what's going on, we can use an awesome little environment variable called [`QSG_VISUALIZE`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-visualcanvas-scenegraph-renderer.html#visualizing). Specifically, we want to use the [`overdraw`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-visualcanvas-scenegraph-renderer.html#visualizing-overdraw) visualisation, which gives us a nice rotating 3D box containing our scene. Even with our `PropertyChanges` above, you can see that the stacking order of the item is unchanged:

[image: stacking order overdraw visualisation]

To ensure that the item is rendered on top of everything, you need to parent it to an item that is actually above everything. We can do this by adding an `Item` to the end of `tiles.qml`:

```
Item {
    id: dragContainer
    anchors.fill: parent
}
```

Add a property to the `DragTile` component that gives the delegate access to the container:

```
property Item dragParent
```

Then, assign the container in `tiles.qml`:

```
delegate: DragTile { colorKey: "red"; dragParent: dragContainer }
```

Next, modify the `parent` property of the `ParentChange` in `DragTile.qml`:

```
ParentChange { target: tile; parent: dragParent }
```

The end result:

[image: stacking order correct visualisation]

Note that I intentionally excluded the "back" button, but if you wanted to make it go above that as well for some reason, you can just move `dragContainer` higher up the hierarchy.

Comment: i changed the parent to a top view it still stays below all views and also if i change the parent grid item is not going back to the correct position

Comment: @Mitch can you please check this question 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40085507/view-item-gets-dropped-outside-drop-area-in-qml/40088897?noredirect=1#comment67740392_40088897